# Creating XML in PHP using SimpleXML with special characters

Tags: php, mysql, xml, apache-flex, special-characters

I am working on project in `flex 3`, where user enters some text which is to be stored in a `mysql` database and shown later. I am using `XML` for data transfer from flex to php and vice-versa. `SimpleXMLElement` in `php` is being used to create the `XML`. The problem is the `XML` breaks on special characters.

Here is sample code:

FLEX:

```
var someXML:XML = <root><data>somedata</data><data>...</data> ... </root>
var data:Object = {};
data.xmlData = someXML;

saveDataService.send(data);
```

Here `somedata` is the data entered by the user. In `php`, I extract the `someXML` using `SimpleXMLElement` and store it to `mysql`. There is no problem till here. Even if `somedata` has special characters its working fine and data is stored properly.

Now, in the other case, getting data from database and showing in flex, the response from the php breaks with an error:

> *SimpleXMLElement::addChild() [simplexmlelement.addchild]:
>   unterminated entity reference*

I tried using `urlencode` in php, and `decodeURI` function in flex, but the decoded string is not the same, few special characters are still `%xy` after decoding.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: by doing some trail and error, I found that the XML breaks when there is a '&' character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you have a dangling `&` character in your xml, then you have an xml syntax error. Its nothing to do with SimpleXML or any other parser complaining. I'd suggest you fix this even before the data gets into the db, better yet, before it is sent to the php service.

Gordon's suggestion works, for `&` at least. You'll likely face the problem with other characters like `<`, `"` etc., later on and you'll be facing pretty much the same thing.

I'd suggest you do a `htmlentities` like operation on the *text* data in side the xml, **not** including the xml tags themselves. Following code taken from http://thingsthatwork.net/index.php/2008/06/26/html-entities-and-actionscript/

```
XML(new XMLNode(XMLNodeType.TEXT_NODE, "content with special chars like & and others")).toXMLString();
```

Haven't tested the above, but it should return you the *sanitized* content that you can put into xml. It should effectively turn `&` chars into `&amp;`, all of them. i.e., This should also turn occurences of `&gt;` to `&amp;gt;`, so be wary of that.

Let me know if you need anything else. Also, how ya doin' man!? ;)

**Edit**: Oh, keep in mind, it has been long time since I used php, so some of the info above might be a bit off. Please correct me guys. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the response. Will give and try. Yeah I am doing good.

Answer (score 3):

In XML an `&` starts an entity. The `;` ends it. When you have a literal `&` you will get an *unterminated entity reference*. Change all `&` to `&amp;` that are not entities already, e.g. dont change `&gt;` to `&amp;gt;`. Or put somedata into CDATA sections.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping your data with htmlspecialchars before passing it to SimpleXMLElement::addChild

Comment: That would turn the required xml syntax characters too into html entities, which would render the content un-parseable by SimpleXML

Comment: No, try calling the function like this:
$document->addChild('myElement', htmlspecialchars($value));

Otherwise just use DOMDocument which does it automatically ;-)